# Voltage of capacitors after long time ($RC$ Circuit)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, batteries

I'm currently taking a course in electromagnetism, and I got stuck with this problem:

**The Problem:**

All of the resistors and capacitors have the same values, $R$ and $C$ respectively.
The circuit is analyzed after a very long time. What is the voltage on the capacitors?

**My Reasoning:**

After a long time, the capacitors charge up and every loop that contains a capacitor has no current flowing.

**C1** was charging through current **I**, **I** then was split and the rest of the capacitors where charging with current **I1**.

So the moment the current stopped flowing in the circuit, **C1** built up **Q1** charge and the other capacitors built up the same amount of charge **Q2** (Same current flow through them for the same amount of time)

For some reason I get weird results, I would really appreciate it if someone could point to my mistake

[image]

Comment: After a long time all the capacitors look like open circuits, including C4. Therefore there is no current anywhere in the circuit after a long time.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all capacitors initially discharged, after the battery is connected, and your top-left capacitor becomes fully charged, no current can flow through it.  Initially the remaining capacitors will begin storing charge.

But, after time passes and the top-left capacitor heads toward battery voltage the remaining capacitors will discharge through the closed path of the 2 resistors. They will all eventually have zero charge, thus zero voltage.

From a simulation using [ATP](https://www.emtp.org/), here is what those voltages would look like using a battery voltage of 10V suddenly applied with C = 1μF and R = 1$\Omega$.

[image]

And here are the capacitor currents...

[image]

Comment: I would argue that the voltage across the capacitors in the right hand loop is undefined. My thinking is, the node between C2, and the three parallel capacitors (C3, C4, and, uh, the other C4) is _floating._ It has no D.C. connection to any other part of the circuit. The only thing we can say for sure is that the voltage across all of those capacitors has to be the _same_ because of the way they are connected through the two resistors, but that voltage could be 0V or it could be a million Volts, or it could be anything. (Assuming ideal capacitors that do not leak any current, of course.)

Comment: I believe the question presented to the OP implies that the capacitors are initially uncharged.

Comment: In other words, you are basing your answer on arbitrarily chosen initial conditions. That's a perfectly valid thing to do, but I'm just pointing out that the initial conditions are _your_ choice, and not specified anywhere in the original problem statement.

Comment: Yes, with the sparse information given, only common sense suggests the initial conditions are zero.  There is no mention to ignore the inherent inductance present in a real capacitor either.  In other words, let’s treat this like what it is, a simple problem for a student learning fundamentals. I have added my assumption to my answer.